# How to change my laptop os from window to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, operating-system

I'm trying to install ubuntu at my computer. But I can't. Because my computer can't find ubuntu boot manager. This laptop is LG ultra PC(15U780).
At first I tried to install multi-booting. But it was not work. Grub was not opened. So I can only use window. At Boot Option Menu, there was only a window boot manager.
And then I erased window and install ubuntu through the ubuntu install menu. Then, I restarted laptop, there is a error.
"Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed. Insert Recovery Media and Hit any key. Then Select 'Boot Manager' to choose a new Boot Device or to Boot Recovery Media"

I made a USB using rufus. My laptop only recognized usb which is selected GPT at partion and NTFS at file system.
And I tried all menu of ubuntu install like erase disk and install or somthing else etc...

Lastly I'm very sorry that English sentences and grammar because I'm not a person who lived in English based-country. Pleas understand my English.

Comment: This kind of question should be asked at superuser.com. Stackoverflow is only for programming related questions. For your problem, you should install Windows first then install Ubuntu. Windows just erases the early boot process of grub but Ubuntu will leave you the option of installing aside Windows and automatically detect your Windows installation. Otherwise, you can install Windows and resize your Windows partitions to leave some space for Ubuntu. Then install Ubuntu on that partition and GRUB. Boot into Ubuntu and configure GRUB to let you choose which one to boot when you power on.

Comment: I don't know all the details but that should work. Most likely you firmware is UEFI so UEFI launches a small app from a FAT32 partition that has to be the first partition of the hard-disk. You really should either get a second ssd and plug it inside the computer on a second SATA connector or use a small USB adapter for SATA hard-disks which come at around 15$. Then boot from that external hard-disk for Ubuntu. SSDs cost maybe 40-60$ depending on the size so it shouldn't be a problem (around 70-80$).